# Legality of Outer Space Colonization

Tags: colonization, law

Is it legal for a private entity to found a space colony?

Ex. Build a rotating habitat in orbit around the Earth and let people live there indefinitely

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Colonizing_Outer_Space/Colonization/Law

Comment: I think if you could actually build it you aren't going to need to worry about that...

Comment: You should note there is potentially a legal difference between orbital habitats and surface habitats, so you may want to specify whether you are interested in one specifically or an overview of both.

Comment: In what jurisdiction? Vatican?

Comment: Lol... international treaty provisions would do I suppose

Answer (score 1):

> The Outer Space Treaty represents the basic legal framework of
>   international space law and, among its principles, it bars States
>   Parties to the Treaty from placing nuclear weapons or any other
>   weapons of mass destruction in orbit of Earth, installing them on the
>   Moon or any other celestial body, or to otherwise station them in
>   outer space. It exclusively limits the use of the Moon and other
>   celestial bodies to peaceful purposes and expressly prohibits their
>   use for testing weapons of any kind, conducting military manoeuvers,
>   or establishing military bases, installations, and fortifications
>   (Art.IV). Moreover, it explicitly forbids any government from claiming
>   a celestial resource such as the Moon or a planet. Art. II of the
>   Treaty states, in fact, that “[o]uter space, including the moon and
>   other celestial bodies, is not subject to national appropriation by
>   claim of sovereignty, by means of use or occupation, or by any other
>   means.”.

(from https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Outer_Space_Treaty_of_1967)

[This question and its answer(s) ("What lunar legalities are currently in place")](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/4460/what-lunar-legalities-are-currently-in-place) will inform somewhat concerning the moon itself, and furthermore refers to the [United Nations Office for Outer Space Affairs](http://www.unoosa.org/), which has reportedly been more active in recent years.